# Step down from 6V to 3V without sacrificing current

Tags: current, voltage-divider

Very new to electronics so I will try to be clear.  I have a 6V 1.8mA power supply and 3 different DC motors - one is 6V and the other 2 are 3V.  All of my motors require ~1mA.  The issue that I am having is that I used a voltage divider to go from 6 - 3V using two resistors and the formula V2 = V1(R2/R2+R1) and my current dropped to .5 mA.  I am sure this is obvious to many but it is not so obvious to me. The current, after dividing, is not enough to turn the 3V motors.  Please point me in the right direction with this.  I have no problems driving to the store if I know what I need to buy.  Thanks.

Comment: Once you draw current from a voltage divider, the voltage drop from R1 gets bigger. So you no longer have a 3 volt line. You need to use an active voltage regulator

Comment: @Makoto I was looking at the MOSFET regulators just now.  Would those work or would something else be better?

Comment: Hmm 1mA motors eh? Maybe a link will prove useful?

Comment: Likely those motors use Amps. You can use a buck-regulator to step down and boost available current.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf NO. you can make, best case, 3.6 mA out of a 1.8 mA coming at 6V from the supply. If the motors use 1000s of mA, then you can't magically make energy appear with a buck regulator. Please don't advertise impossible stuff!

Comment: @Andyaka I looked for the paperwork, but it is lost somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot step down voltage with a resistive voltage divider.

I mean, you can, but then you **must** not draw current from it – the whole idea of why the ratio between the voltage across the lower and the upper resistor is known is that the same current flows through both.

So, your approach can't work.

You need a *voltage regulator* – 3V is pretty common, so you can choose from a variety of devices (go to mouser.com, farnell.com, digikey.com,... and click yourself through to the voltage regulators).

There's generally two classes of regulators:

- Linear Regulators: Basically, imagine an adjustable resistor in series with your load. The resistor is always adjusted such that the voltage across the load is 3 V
- Switch mode power supplies: A little trickier in theory, but imagine you can store electrical energy by magnetizing the core of an electromagnet. By dosing the amount of energy you store, you can keep the voltage across that magnet constant, on average.

Linear regulators will just convert the "extra energy" to heat (ie. since 3V is half of 6V, half of the used power will just be used to heat up your regulator), whereas SMPSes can be made much more efficient.

Now, with your 1.8mA supply, you can only be talking of motors eg. for watches. So, the energy wasted here will be very small, and you can just use any linear 6V-> 3V voltage regulator.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, these motors are very small.  I am browsing mouser as we speak.  This is kind of what I thought. I'll mark as answer in just a bit as this clears it up for me.

Comment: @James here's [the search I'd do on Mouser](http://www.mouser.de/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Power-Management-ICs/Voltage-Regulators-Voltage-Controllers/Linear-Voltage-Regulators/_/N-6j76qZscv7?P=1z0wd7g&Ns=Pricing|0)

Comment: Make sure the device you pick works with a 6V input!

Comment: (and: 3V is not as common as 3.3V output, so you'll find cheaper devices if you not only look for fixed 3V regulators, like I did)

Comment: Thanks.  Electronics is definitely something I wish I started long ago.  I'm just about to finish my BS in computer science and this would have been incredibly useful.